# Correctly distinguish between bool? and bool in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to find out if a variable is either a simple `bool` or a `Nullable<bool>`.

It seems that

```
if(val is Nullable<bool>)
```

returns true for both `bool` and `Nullable<bool>` variables and

```
if(val is bool)
```

also returns true for both `bool` and `Nullable<bool>`.

Basically, I am interesting in finding out if a simple `bool` variable is *true* **OR** if a `Nullable<bool>` variable is *not null*.

What's the way to do this?

Here is the full code:

```
List<string> values = typeof(InstViewModel).GetProperties()
                          .Where(prop => prop != "SubCollection" && prop != "ID" && prop != "Name" && prop != "Level")
                          .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(ivm, null))
                          .Where(val => val != null && (val.GetType() != typeof(bool) || (bool)val == true))      //here I'm trying to check if val is bool and true or if bool? and not null
                          .Select(val => val.ToString())
                          .Where(str => str.Length > 0)
                          .ToList();
```

The `InstViewModel` object:

```
 public class InstViewModel
    {
        public string SubCollection { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public bool Uk { get; set; }
        public bool Eu { get; set; }
        public bool Os { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Mobiles { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Landlines { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> UkNrs { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IntNrs { get; set; }
}
```

The point of my code here is to find out if all of the object's values are `null` (more specifically, to find out any values that are not null and save them in a `List<string>`). This presents a complication in the lambda expression, however, when trying to distinguish between `bool` and `bool?` types in my object (second `Where` statement).

Additionally, since the object contains some string types as well, I am trying to exclude those in my first `.Where` statement (which I am probably not doing right at present as it doesn't seem to be working). But my main goal is to distinguish between `bool` and `bool?` types.

Comment: What is the type of `val`? Do you understand that there's no such thing as a "boxed `Nullable<T>`"?

Comment: @JonSkeet no, I have not used Nullable types before, please explain?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx `.GetType` and `is` use the underlying. `typeof` doesn't and will see the difference.

Comment: @sparta223: Basically as per xanatos' answer. If you box an `int?` you end up with a boxed `int` or a `null` reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet the problem is that I have a lambda expression so I can't do that (see my comment to xanatos' answer), is there another way?

Comment: @sparta223 That is a **completely different** question. I have reopened you question.

Comment: Quoting: "if(val is bool) also returns true for both `bool` and `Nullable<bool>`". That is incorrect, it will return false if the nullable value is null.

Comment: @sparta223: Your LINQ query goes from `prop` to `val` with no intermediate `Select`, which is very odd... the actual "property getting" is earlier, and you're then performing *reference comparisons* against string literals, which is almost certainly a bad idea. I think the best approach would actually be to write an entirely new question with more detail about what you're trying to achieve - it's all a bit of a mess at the moment. I suspect you actually want to write a method `bool HasUsefulValue(PropertyInfo property, object parent)` or something similar.

Comment: @JonSkeet don't see what's the point of creating a new question and asking the same thing. I have included all the code and my question is still the same. If you want you can post an answer but I don't see why I should post a new question

Comment: @sparta223: You wouldn't be asking the same thing. You'd be asking a much clearer question showing exactly what you're trying to achieve - and without changing an *existing* question which has answers to what you originally talked about. The current question is a mess IMO, but just editing it to show what you really want will leave 6 answers which look nonsensical.

Comment: @JonSkeet feel free to propose an edit :)

Comment: @sparta223: No, because as I've said before, editing the existing question would make the existing answers even less meaningful... and I still don't understand your *exact* requirements.

Comment: [How to: Identify a Nullable Type (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx)

Comment: First of all, Jon is right; the crux of your confusion is not understanding how boxing affects nullables. This was a controversial and rather confusing feature added late in the game to C# 2.0.  However I would also note that you are confusing *variables* with the *value of a variable* and you are confusing properties with variables. These are all different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code for getting class instance values:

```
// create class instance
InstViewModel model = new InstViewModel()
{
    Uk = true,
    UkNrs = false,
};

// check all boolean fields are false or null
bool isAllNullOrFalse = (from property in typeof(InstViewModel).GetProperties()
                         let type = property.PropertyType
                         let isBool = type == typeof(bool)
                         where isBool || type == typeof(bool?)
                         let value = property.GetValue(model)
                         select value == null || (isBool && bool.Equals(value, false))).All(e => e);

Console.WriteLine("All values are null or false = {0}", isAllNullOrFalse);
```

Comment: No, the point of my code there is to find out if all of the object's values are null. This presents a complication, however, when trying to distinguish between bool and bool? types in my objects in the lambda expression.

Comment: You use `typeof(InstViewModel)`, but it is a class definition, not an object (class instance). And your `val` if of type `PropertyInfo`, not `bool` or `bool?`.

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope it provides more explanation. It is possible my initial approach is wrong, but hopefully the further info will help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @sparta223, try updated code, is it that you are looking for?

Comment: nearly, could you update the code so that it saves the result in a List? That way I can check if the list is empty, meaning all bool? properties were null and all bool properties were false.

Comment: I just tried your code, it returns true correctly, except when all bools are false and there is a FALSE nullable<bool>. it should return false here because the nullable is not null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79661/discussion-between-general-doomer-and-sparta223).

Answer (score 11):

There is a simple way to check whether a variable is declared as `T` or `T?`:

```
private static bool IsNullable<T>(T val)
{
    return false;
}

private static bool IsNullable<T>(T? val)
    where T : struct
{
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool? val = false;

if (IsNullable(val))
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**
Try the following code for edited question:

```
var boolProps = typeof (InstViewModel).GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
    .Select(prop => (bool)prop.GetValue(ivm, null))
    .Select(v => v ? v.ToString() : String.Empty);

var nullableBoolProps = typeof(InstViewModel).GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
    .Select(prop => (bool?)prop.GetValue(ivm, null))
    .Select(v => v.HasValue ? v.ToString() : String.Empty);

List<string> values = boolProps.Concat(nullableBoolProps)
              .Where(str => str.Length != 0)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question however. How would you implement the above in the lambda expression?

Answer (score 4):

```
typeof(InstViewModel).GetProperties()
  .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(ivm, null))
```

At this point, you have a sequence of type `object`. Each element of that sequence will be an object that can be one of:

1. An instance of a reference type.
2. A boxed instance of a value type.
3. `null`.

The `null` case can happen either because you had a null value for a property which was of reference type, or a null value for a property that was a nullable value type; there's no way to tell the difference at here. Likewise there's no way to tell the difference between a boxed `bool` that came from a `bool` value or a boxed `bool` that came from a `bool?` value.

You need to examine the type of the property, not the property's value:

```
isNullableProperty = property.PropertyType.IsGenericType
  && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
```

But to just filter to only `bool` and `bool?` then:

```
typeof(InstViewModel).GetProperties()
  .Where(
     prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool)
     || prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
```

Comment: @sparta223 what are you trying `PropertyType` on, the property or the value? You need to do it **before** the `Select(prop => prop.GetValue(ivm, null))`

Comment: I suspect the bottom part should be `prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool)` etc. `prop.GetType()` will just be `typeof(PropertyInfo)` or some implementation subclass...

Comment: @JonHanna yes I put it before the select, but I still don't see a GetPropetyType(). I see you edited your question and it now says GetType()?

Comment: It was edited by someone else and they replaced my mistake with a worse mistake. It should be `PropertyType` (which is a property of `PropertyInfo`, not a method, my mistake was based on the memory that `PropertyInfo` has quite a few methods starting with `Get`, but `PropertyType` is a more normal property).

Answer (score 3):

You can distinguish the boolean and nullable boolean properties before you evaluate them.  Then there is no need to worry about whether they evaluate to a `bool` or a `Nullable<bool>`:

```
var nullableBooleanProperties = typeof(InstViewModel).Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?));
```

Then you can simply write these out to a list of strings:

```
var values = nullableBooleanProperties.Select(prop => prop.GetValue(ivm)).Where(val => val != null).Select(val => val.ToString());
```

Putting these together gives:

```
var values = typeof(InstViewModel).Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
    .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(ivm)).Where(val => val != null)
    .Select(val => val.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

which gives you the list you are looking for.

Comment: your answer also works, however, someone posted the same answer before you so I accepted theirs. I have up-voted your answer, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a response to the initial question - ignore this.**

When you "box" a nullable value (so you put it in an `object`), it is transformed in its underlying type (`bool` in your case) or in `null`... So if you have

```
bool? value = true;
object value2 = value;
```

now `value2.GetType() == typeof(bool)`

Comment: thanks xantos, is there another way to do this, as my if statement is in a lamda expression so I can't box the value:

.Where(val => val != null && (val.GetType() != typeof(bool) || (bool)val == true))

Answer (score 2):

According to your question

> Basically, I am interest*ed* in finding out if a simple bool variable is true OR if a Nullable variable is not null.

- to tell if a simple boolVariable is true

  ```
   if(boolVariable){
        //bool variable, not nullable
   }
  ```
- to tell if your nullableVariable is not null

  ```
   if(nullableVariable.HasValue){
       //a nullable variable is not null
   }
  ```
- to tell if nullable bool variable is true or/and not null, use the `??` operator

  ```
  if(variable??false){
     //then I'm sure that this is not null and has value=true
  }
  ```

So in definitive you can use the following code for both nullable bool and bool variables

```
     if(variables!=null &&variables!=false){/*This may give a warning message but it works*/}
```

or

```
   if(((bool?)variable)??false){
      /*variable is not null and is true*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
((bool?)val).HasValue
```

This will return `true`, if `val` is a `bool` **or** if `val` is a `bool?` which value is not `null`.

On the other hand,

```
!((bool?)val).HasValue
```

will only return `true` if val is `bool?` **and** its value is `null`.

Will not that test suffice in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<string> values = typeof(InstViewModel).GetProperties()
    .Select(prop => new { N = prop.Name, T = prop.PropertyType, V = prop.GetValue(ivm, null) })
    .Where(prop => prop.N != "SubCollection" && prop.N != "ID" && prop.N != "Name" && prop.N != "Level")
    .Where(val => (val.V != null && val.T.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Nullable<bool>))) || Convert.ToBoolean(val.V))                    
    .Select(val => val.V.ToString())
    .Where(str => str.Length > 0)
    .ToList();
```